# White space caused by next js __next-build-watcher div (created by usecontext)

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

I have a bar at the bottom of the page that is notifying the user when their email is sent.

This bar is created using useContext in React/Next.js. Here is the code in Codebox:

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-flower-k8igm)

When I go to the page I see a white space on the bottom of the bottom nav:

[image]

From the browser I can see the space is caused by the notification bar that when sending an email looks like this:

[image]

On the browser:

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of the white space? I have tried css but hasn't worked.

Comment: That element is `position: fixed` and therefore won't have any impact on the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but for anyone that stumbles onto this:

This is not a production element, but only exists when you use `next dev`. It does not affect your page view.